# Cron to delete files

Tags: cron, delete

In Ubuntu 17.10 the command

```
find /Home/khemtit/Documents/Tijdelijk/ -mtime +1 -type f -delete>$
```

delete my files older than 1 day. But I have no result in combination with a cron.

Could you please inform me about my mistake in the line below?

My command is:

```
15 00  * * * find /home/khemtit/Documents/Tijdelijk/ -mtime +1 -type f -delete>$
```

By <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> I do see the text:

```
File Name to Write: tmpcrontab.OV51lh/crontab
```

I believe the cron is installed correctly because “service cron status” gives the message:

```
cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-01-29 18:29:16 +07; 5min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 861 (cron)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─861 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

Comment: Did you try with an external script ?
ie write
find /home/khemtit/Documents/Tijdelijk/ -mtime +1 -type f -delete
in an executable script like /usr/local/cleanup, and

15 00  * * * /usr/local/cleanup

Don't use >$

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. It's working now.

The correct line must be:

```
06 19 * * * find /home/khemtit/Documents/Tijdelijk/ -mtime +1 -type f -delete
```

My mistake was about an extra space and the `$` in line:

```
15 00  * * * find /home/khemtit/Documents/Tijdelijk/ -mtime +1 -type f -delete>$
```